# Problems with DNS resolution

Tags: linux, dns, dig

i have a problem with DNS resolution.

The routing seems to work, because I can ping other servers and traceroute also works.

But using dig, i get the a address for 'a.root-servers.net not found error.

I'm on opensuse leap 15.4.

```
dig +trace google.de @1.1.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.16.20 <<>> +trace google.de @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
.                       515724  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       515724  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20230209050000 20230127040000 951 . PHk0oAh7B64P4athdNaFRLc2Q/IPUaMhDOdxt98tIfOy7AN4BvWteUMg e1lmRQrHW1V6hPAGoKxNm72DV03Dvg25qZyFC8i2pm5ynEOXHUaGNDVQ +pTLw7xFB9l53WmkEXkjBXa4Zym7BankEClAWJOguovlO3jkFHcdVc6J OAT/jNzQ6RCorSSi027oQ+tc2zfc64IFCqg3z43VQx6eFtW+FtzUAvGT lmpbaOiKiZwEOb7Q9ltpqJc8c62uJWr3l2AU0f6ya4bqEU7ELVw5WA90 A6pC9/L2VQL0h83dnzRlRVTR8wwL2dO50sAOyuuItmgJxj/D2oHJi/A+ qnGIrw==
couldn't get address for 'a.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'b.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'c.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'd.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'e.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'f.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'g.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'h.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'i.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'j.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'k.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'l.root-servers.net': not found
couldn't get address for 'm.root-servers.net': not found
dig: couldn't get address for 'a.root-servers.net': no more
```

Edit:
Current `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
### /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to /var/run/netconfig/resolv.conf
### autogenerated by netconfig!
#
# Before you change this file manually, consider to define the
# static DNS configuration using the following variables in the
# /etc/sysconfig/network/config file:
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SEARCHLIST
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_FORWARDER
# or disable DNS configuration updates via netconfig by setting:
#     NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY=''
#
# See also the netconfig(8) manual page and other documentation.
#
### Call "netconfig update -f" to force adjusting of /etc/resolv.conf.
```

Comment: Please remember, don't drip feed info. Bring up the NM gui and add it there. Check whether you are running DHCP and why it is not supplying DNS info. What is currently in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: I added the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @Bib what do you mean with: "don't drip feed info"?

Comment: `drip feed` - as in giving minimal info and supplying bits here and there only when asked rather than giving as much info on the problem as possible. `/etc/resolv.conf` has no `nameserver` entries so it's no wonder resolving does not occur. We still do not know if you are running static or dhcp interfaces. Nor do we know if any dhcp server is set up correctly or what the setup for NM is.

Comment: I configured the server to have a static IP address. I see, that its a problem, that there is no nameserver, but shouldn't dig be successfull if I specify a DNS Server (i tried: `dig +trace google.de @1.1.1.1`) so even if there is no dns server configured, dig should use 1.1.1.1 right?

Comment: No, because you have the trace flag on. You initially ask for the root servers from 1.1.1.1 which replies, variously, a.root-servers.net etc. The resolving then returns to your local control, which as there is no resolver name set, fails. Running tcpdump for port 53 will show you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was very confused and didn't even know where to start. I have it fixed now and I will write an answer with the solution later!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a named/bind installation in place, those root IP addresses should be part of your named/bind installation (probably /etc/bind9/db.root in Debian/Ubuntu and /var/named/named.root in the Red Hat branch). You may have an outdated file, in which case you can get the latest one at https://www.internic.net/domain/named.root.

If you don't have a named/bind installation, then the DNS server which is resolving host names into IP addresses for you should be the one resolving those.

Comment: I cannot find a db.root or named.root file on my opensuse system and I couldn't find an answer on google either. Can I just create the file myself?

Comment: Running `yast2 lan` results in: Network is currently handled by NetworkManager.

Comment: if i add a nameserver to `/etc/resolv.conf`, i just have to write `nameserver 8.8.8.8` for example?

Comment: First thing is to know who is resolving your DNS queries. Could you please check the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` to know if it is localhost (127.0.0.1), some external DNS server or something else?

Answer (score 0):

@Bib helped in the comment section under my question.

The problem was simply a missing nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
I thought, that I did not have to provide one, because I specified it in the `dig` command. But as @Bib mentioned, this is not the case when `dig` is used with the `trace` flag.
@Bib explained it:

> You initially ask for the root servers from 1.1.1.1 which replies, variously, a.root-servers.net etc. The resolving then returns to your local control, which as there is no resolver name set, fails. Running tcpdump for port 53 will show you.

To solve it I changed the `NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS` variable in `/etc/sysconfig/network/config`. To: `NETCONFIG_DNS_STATIC_SERVERS="1.1.1.1"`.
Then it is necessary to update `/var/run/netconfig/resolv.conf` (this is symlinked with `/etc/resolv.conf` by running `netconfig update -f`.
The changes in `/etc/sysconfig/network/config` will then be applied to `/etc/resolv.conf`.